# Expand formatted string into multiple lines based on substrings with particular delimiter

Tags: php, regex, replace, combinations, user-input

I am building a web app which user type special kind of code (see below), which my this script "decodes" and creates individual variations of the code and then send each of this code to the SQL query. For now, I am stuck in the part where codes need to convert this:

```
 A1 B2 - C3 + D4 / E5 / E6 C3 / A5
```

to these (interpreting slash "/" as OR):

```
 A1 B2 - C3 + D4 C3
 A1 B2 - C3 + E5 C3
 A1 B2 - C3 + E6 C3
 A1 B2 - C3 + D4 A5
 A1 B2 - C3 + E5 A5
 A1 B2 - C3 + E6 A5
```

This is what I got for now:

```
// User input
$input = "A1 B2 - C3 + D4 / E5 / E6 C3 / A5";
print_r($input);

// Check how many times user input have "/" (returns INT in $occurencesOfOR and makes complex array $matches of matched substrings)
$occurencesOfOR = preg_match_all("/(?: \/ )?(?:[A-IK-Za-ik-z]|Aa)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}[A-Za-z]? \/ (?:[A-IK-Za-ik-z]|Aa)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}[A-Za-z]?(?: \/ (?:[A-IK-Za-ik-z]|Aa)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}[A-Za-z]?)*/", $input, $matches);
print_r($occurencesOfOR);

// Replacing places of matched pattern with X
$dummyCode = "X";
$inputStripped = preg_replace("/(?: \/ )?(?:[A-IK-Za-ik-z]|Aa)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}[A-Za-z]? \/ (?:[A-IK-Za-ik-z]|Aa)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}[A-Za-z]?(?: \/ (?:[A-IK-Za-ik-z]|Aa)[1-9][0-9]{0,2}[A-Za-z]?)*/", $dummyCode, $input);
print_r($inputStripped);

print_r($matches);

// Creating simple array with individual OR codes
$orCodesArray = [];
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
    array_push($orCodesArray, $match);
}

print_r($orCodesArray);

// Creating multidimensional array from individual codes created by preg_split()
$individualCodesSubarrays = [];
foreach ($orCodesArray as $code) {
    $codeSet = preg_split("/ \/ /", $code);
    array_push($individualCodesSubarrays, $codeSet);
}

print_r($individualCodesSubarrays);

// Count how many subarrays has $individualCodesArray (returns INT)
$counterOfArrays = count($individualCodesSubarrays);
echo $counterOfArrays;

// Getting position of X-es in stripped user input
$lastPos = 0;
$positions = [];
$position = "";
while (($lastPos = strpos($inputStripped, $dummyCode, $lastPos)) !== false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($dummyCode);
}
foreach ($positions as $position) {
    echo $position."\n";
}
```

But from there I don't know how to pursue further. I cannot find a solution how to make a function that will replace 1st `X` with each of `D4 / E5 / E6` and 2nd `X` with each of `C3 / A5` to make all possible combinations as stated above. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I succeeded in progress to make this, but still have a problem to make it work.

```
 // Addition to the upper code at the end
$inputStripped2 = [];
for ($c=0; $c < $counterOfArrays; $c++) {
$individualCodesSubrray = $individualCodesSubarrays[$c];
print_r($individualCodesSubrray);
$countCodes = count($individualCodesSubrray);
echo $countCodes."\n";
for ($x=0; $x < $countCodes; $x++) {
    $dummyCodeX = "X".$c;
    array_push($inputStripped2, str_replace($dummyCodeX, $individualCodesSubrray[$x], $inputStripped));
    }
print_r($inputStripped2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could achieve what you want is to first split the string on either space (on its own), '+' or '-', e.g.

```
$input = "A1 B2 - C3 + D4 / E5 / E6 C3 / A5";
$parts = preg_split('/(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\s+(?=[A-IK-Za-ik-z])|\s+([+-])\s+/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

This gives:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => A1
    [1] => B2
    [2] => -
    [3] => C3
    [4] => +
    [5] => D4 / E5 / E6
    [6] => C3 / A5 
)
```

These values can then be further split on `/` using:

```
foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    $part = preg_split('#\s+/\s+#', $part);
}
```

This gives the following array of arrays:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => A1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => B2
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => - 
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => C3
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => +
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [0] => D4
        [1] => E5
        [2] => E6
    )
    [6] => Array (
        [0] => C3
        [1] => A5
    ) 
)
```

You can now take the cross-products of these arrays using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and a function like this:

```
function cross_product($array, $value) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($array as $arr) {
        foreach ($value as $val) {
            $output[] = array_merge($arr, array($val));
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$init = array_map(function ($v) { return array($v); }, array_shift($parts));
$outputs = array_reduce($parts, 'cross_product', array($init));
```

Finally you can output imploded versions of each of the `$outputs` array to give your desired result:

```
foreach ($outputs as $output) {
    echo implode(' ', $output) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A1 B2 - C3 + D4 C3 
A1 B2 - C3 + D4 A5
A1 B2 - C3 + E5 C3
A1 B2 - C3 + E5 A5
A1 B2 - C3 + E6 C3
A1 B2 - C3 + E6 A5
```

Alternatively, for input `"A1 / B2 - C3 + D4 / E5 / E6 C3 + A5"` you will get:

```
A1 - C3 + D4 C3 + A5 
A1 - C3 + E5 C3 + A5 
A1 - C3 + E6 C3 + A5 
B2 - C3 + D4 C3 + A5 
B2 - C3 + E5 C3 + A5 
B2 - C3 + E6 C3 + A5
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9ICTq)

Comment: I tried your code and it worked well for given user input, but when I change it to for example `A1 / B2 - C3 + D4 / E5 / E6 C3 + A5`, for some reason, it not work.

Comment: @BorisJ. sorry about that - there was an issue with inputs that *started* with an alternation. I've fixed the code (the assignment of `$init` was the problem) and updated the demo.

Comment: It works like charm. Thank you. I am interested if it is possible to correct my approach to work also (updated code above)?

Comment: @BorisJ. The issue is that you need to do a cross-product of each of the alternations (words separated by `/`. The only practical way to do that for an arbitrary number of elements is through recursion (which is what my `array_reduce` is effectively doing).

Answer (score 0):

I think I would engage a conditionally looped call of `preg_replace_callback()` and expand delimited substrings one-set-at-a-time until there are no more "or" expressions to expand.

My regular expression will either match a whole line of text or nothing at all. With your sample input, the first loop will expand the second/last set (`C3 / A5`) into 2 separate lines.  On the second loop, the first set (`D4 / E5 / E6`) will be expand the generated lines into 6 separate lines.  The third loop will not find any sets to expand, so `$count` will be `0` and the loop will break.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YqBC0))

```
$expression = 'A1 B2 - C3 + D4 / E5 / E6 C3 / A5';

do {
    $expression = preg_replace_callback(
         '~(.*?)([A-Z0-9]{2}(?: / [A-Z0-9]{2})+)(.*)~',
         fn($m) =>
             implode(
                 "\n",
                 array_map(
                     fn($v) => "{$m[1]}$v{$m[3]}",
                     explode(' / ', $m[2]),
                 )
             ),
         $expression,
         1,
         $count
    );
} while($count);

echo $expression;
```